# How do I erase sets of solutions from Solve based on criteria?

Tags: equation-solving

I have this list

```
Solutions = {{"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., 
  "L3" -> 0., "Rin" -> -1.09141*10^22}, {"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., 
  "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., 
  "Rin" -> -1.09141*10^22}, {"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., 
  "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., "Rin" -> -22777.6}, {"C1" -> 0.,
   "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., 
  "Rin" -> -22777.6}, {"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0.,
   "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., "Rin" -> 59.7556}, {"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0.,
   "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., 
  "Rin" -> 59.7556}, {"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., 
  "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., "Rin" -> 100.}}
```

I want to eliminate any solution with a negative element. I have tried to do

```
Solutions = Select[Solutions, FreeQ[#, NegativeReals] &]
```

It does not work, gives me the empty set as a solution. How to fix this?

Comment: `Select[Solutions, Min[Values[#]] >= 0 &]`

Comment: Not related to the question, but could you specify the domain as `NonNegativeReals` so that these solutions would not be generated in the first place? I deleted my previous comment as a `PositiveReals` domain would exclude all zero valued solutions.

Comment: You could also include the positive condition in `Solve`. For instance, compare `Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && x - y == 1, {x, y}]` with `Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 1 && x - y == 1 && {x, y} >= 0, {x, y}]` (or as Syed suggested, the domain options if you have version 12.0+)

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you can create a list

```
list = Values[Solutions] // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
```

and exclude any sublists with one negative element

```
nonneg =Pick[list, UnitStep @@@ list, 1]
```

**Edit**

Of course, after having the above you can do

```
params = ((Solutions // Rationalize[#, 0] &) /. Rule -> (#1 &))[[1]];
Thread[params -> #] & /@ nonneg
```

to get

> [image: final]

And of course, after we have explained the logic we can write a one-liner

```
Thread[First[((Solutions // Rationalize[#, 0] &) /. 
       Rule -> (#1 &))] -> #] & /@ 
 Pick[Values[Solutions] // Rationalize[#, 0] &, 
  UnitStep @@@ Values[Solutions] // Rationalize[#, 0] &, 1]
```

where `Solutions` is taken from the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Another way using `Table`, `If` and `FreeQ`:

```
Table[If[FreeQ[# < 0 & /@ (#[[All, 2]] & /@ sols)[[i]], True] === False, 
Nothing, sols[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[sols]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[#, Values@# ∈ NonNegativeReals] & /@ Solutions
```

Or

```
Select[Values@# ∈ NonNegativeReals &][Solutions]
```

---

Result:

> ```
> {{"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., 
>   "L3" -> 0., "Rin" -> 59.7556}, {"C1" -> 0., "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., 
>   "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., "Rin" -> 59.7556}, {"C1" -> 0., 
>   "C2" -> 0., "C3" -> 0., "L1" -> 0., "L2" -> 0., "L3" -> 0., 
>   "Rin" -> 100.}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
Replace[Solutions, x_ /; AnyTrue[Values[x],Negative] -> Nothing,{1}]


(* {
    {C1 -> 0., C2 -> 0., C3 -> 0., L1 -> 0., L2 -> 0., L3 -> 0., Rin -> 59.7556}, 

    {C1 -> 0., C2 -> 0., C3 -> 0., L1 -> 0., L2 -> 0., L3 -> 0., Rin -> 59.7556}, 

    {C1 -> 0., C2 -> 0., C3 -> 0., L1 -> 0., L2 -> 0., L3 -> 0., Rin -> 100.}

    } *)
```

Comment: Also `Select[Solutions, NoneTrue[Values[#], Negative]&]`